# Django get filename without url

Tags: django, django-storage

I get a file with this commannd:

`src = request.POST.get('src', '')`

But the output is: https://url.com/path/filename.jpg

How can I just get path/filename.jpg?

regards
Christopher

Comment: You can parse the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I wrote a 3 lines command, one line would be better:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os    

url = request.POST.get('src', '')
filepath = urlparse(url).path
src = path + (os.path.basename(filepath))
```